# Open the saved file with the changes made to the Rich text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, save, richtextbox, file-writing

I am new to C#. I am trying to build a notepad application. This how I am trying to write my file and save my file which is in a rich text. But when I make the text bold and save it and try to open the saved file I can't see the bold text. I only see the plain text that is inside the file.

What are the changes I should make in my code so that I can see the change I make in my rich text box?

```
var _myRichTextBox = (MyRichTextBox)myTabControlZ.TabPages[myTabControlZ.SelectedIndex].Controls[0];

if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    String filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
    if (filename != "")
    {
        File.WriteAllText(filename, "");
        StreamWriter strw = new StreamWriter(filename);
        strw.Write(_myRichTextBox.richTextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2578222/5174469) and tell me please wheather it works

Comment: You are saving text and there os no formatting in text. Save (and Load) `Rtf`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't save the formatting information. You save only the plain string content. The RichTextBox has tools to accomplish that.

The simplest solution here would be to use the [RichTextBox.SaveFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bf5hy2e(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It will save it as `*.RTF` file and make sure that the format remains intact.

```
_myRichTextBox.SaveFile(filename);
```

to load the content back again use the [RichTextBox.LoadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
_myRichTextBox.LoadFile(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save it as .rtf to save any format.

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                String filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                if (filename != "")
                {
                    _myRichTextBox.SaveFile(filename);
                }
            }
```